# concatenar cadenas sin el \0 en c

Tags: c, string

Tengo que repetir `cadena2` tantas veces como quepa en `cadena1`, para eso uso `strcat`, el problema que tengo es que cada vez que se contatena se hace con `\0` por lo cual al querer trabajar con los caracteres me esta ocasionando conflicto.

```
int i,cont=0;
char a[50], b[50],aux[50];

printf("ingrese cadena1: ");
fgets(a,50,stdin);

printf("ingrese cadena2: ");
fgets(b,50,stdin);

for(i=0;i<strlen(b)-1;i++){
aux[i]=b[i];                //aux va a ser donde repita cadena2
}

 while(cont<(strlen(a)/strlen(b))){ //hago esto por que quiero repetir cadena2
 strcat(aux,b);                     //las veces que quepan en cadena1
 cont++;
 }

 for(i=0;i<strlen(a)-1;i++){          //mostrar posición y que contiene aux
  printf("%d=%c\n",i,aux[i]);
}
/* la salida de esto sera:
(ejemplo poniendo holagg en cadena1 y ki en cadena2.
k        y lo que quiero       k
i        que salga seria:      i
$                              k
k                              i
i                              k
$                              i
*/
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> el problema que tengo es que cada vez que se contatena se hace con \0

Esta afirmación es falsa. `strcat` **no concatena** con `\0`, sino que añade, dicho caracter **al final de la cadena**. Es decir, si tu tienes:

```
cad = "hola\0"
```

y haces

```
strcat(cad, "adios");
```

El resultado será

```
cad = "holaadios\0"
```

Como ves, coge el `\0` que había al final de la cadena original y lo desplaza al final de la cadena resultante.

Revisando el código, tu programa tiene varios errores:

**Sobra una copia**

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(b)-1;i++){
aux[i]=b[i];                
}
```

Esta copia esta mal por varias razones:

1. No finalizas la cadena con `\0`, luego las posteriores llamdas a `strcat` no funcionarán como esperas (buscaran el mencionado `\0` que a saber dónde lo encuentran)
2. La división `strlen(a) / strlen(b)` no tiene en cuenta esta copia... luego el resultado seá que habrá una copia más de las deseadas. Esto implica que puedes acabar escribiendo fuera de los límites del array `aux`, lo que puede provocar que pises memoria de otras variables y que tu programa se comporte de forma errática.
3. La división `strlen(a) / strlen(b)` no tiene en cuenta que el último caracter de `a` y `b`, dado que estás usando `fgets`, es el de salto de línea. Si no eliminas ese caracter la división puede darte resultados incorrectos.

Así que ya sabes, esas líneas sobran.

**Falta una inicialización**

`aux` no está inicializada, y debería. Dado que es `strcat`quien se va a dedicar a rellenar esta variable, lo esperable es que su primer caracter sea `\0`, o, dicho de otra manera, que tenga un string de longitud 0:

```
char aux[50] = "";
```

**Bucles que se quedan cortos**

Todo tu código está saplicado de `strlen(x)-1`. ¿Por qué ese `-1`?

Ese añadido no tiene razón de ser. Te estás liando con el hecho de que los índices empiezen en cero:

```
// indices  -> [0] [1] [2] [ 3]
cad = "abc" -> 'a' 'b' 'c' '\0'

strlen(cad) -> 3

// Bucle de 0 a 2, imprime 3 caracteres: abc
for( int i=0; i<strlen(cad); i++ )
  printf("%c", cad[i]);
```

Así que, como ves, los bucles no deberían sufrir ese `-1`.

**El bucle final está mal**

El último bucle itera sobre la longitud de `a`... ¿Por qué razón?

Se supone que en `aux` se va a almacenar la cadena `b` **completa** varias veces, luego salvo que `strlen(a)` sea múltiplo de `strlen(b)`, la longitud final de `aux` será menor que la longitud de `a`. Trabajar en el rango `(0,strlen(a))` provocará, la mayoría de las veces, que se impriman caracteres raros al final de la secuencia.

Yo sustituiría ese bucle por este otro:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(aux);i++)
{
  printf("%d=%c\n",i,aux[i]);
}
```

Aplicando estos cambios a mi me queda el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void ReadString(char str[50])
{
  fgets(str,50,stdin);

  int pos = strchr(Name, '\n'));
  if( pos != NULL )
    str[pos] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char a[50], b[50],aux[50] = "";

  printf("ingrese cadena1: ");
  ReadString(a);

  printf("ingrese cadena2: ");
  ReadString(b);

  for( int cont = 0; cont < strlen(a) / strlen(b); ++cont )
  {
    strcat(aux, b);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<strlen(aux);i++)
  {          
    printf("%d=%c\n",i,aux[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estaba a mirar tu código y mismo que cambiantes para ser más cerca de mi respuesta (correcta), **aún está errado**.

Answer (score 2):

**No necesitas cambiar mucho tú codigo**.

Tu problema no es en el terminador de *strings*, pero los terminadores de lineas.

```
int main() {
    int i, cont = 0;
    char a[50], b[50];
    char aux[50] = "";

    printf("ingrese cadena1: ");
    fgets(a, 50, stdin);
    a[strcspn(a, "\r\n")] = '\0';

    printf("ingrese cadena2: ");
    fgets(b, 50, stdin);
    b[strcspn(b, "\r\n")] = '\0';

    while (cont < (strlen(a) / strlen(b)))
    {                   //hago esto por que quiero repetir cadena2
        strcat(aux, b); //las veces que quepan en cadena1
        cont++;
    }

    //mostrar posición y que contiene aux
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(aux); i++)
        printf("%d=%c\n", i, aux[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cierto, usa `fgets`, que a diferencia de `gets` no elimina el caracter de salto de línea.

Comment: Qué bién que lo hace así, ya que *gets* está *deprecated*.

Comment: soy más de C++... estas funciones no las uso prácticamente nunca

Comment: ¿Usas traductor para escribir en español? Tus frases son atípicas

Comment: No es problema, solo curiosidad :)

Comment: En la realidad para compiladores modernos, creo que no habria problema como estaba, solo cambié por compatibilidad.

Comment: Sólo sugerí que podía darme el crédito merecido por la respuesta correcta (pero eso se podía hacer hasta en su respuesta).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91242/discussion-between-eferion-and-sbrubes).

Answer (score 1):

Si trabajas con `strcat()` esta función trabaja con `\0` y tal y como has dicho, trabajar con `\0` te da problemas, así que lo mejor va a ser que tu mismo te hagas esa concatenación a "mano" con bucles. En este enlace puede ver una posible implementación de la función `strcat()`, la cual puedes adaptar para que a ti te sirva: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcat